# Square root to complex exponential

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Let's consider the following quantity:

$$K = \sqrt{\frac{c}{a + i b}}$$

where $i$ is the imaginary unit and $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it possible to express it in the complex exponential form? That is

$$K = \alpha e^{i\beta}$$

It could be not immediate to compute $\alpha$ as $\sqrt{(\mathrm{Re} \{ K \})^2 + (\mathrm{Im} \{ K \})^2}$ and $\beta$ as $\arctan$ of $\mathrm{Im} \{ K \} / \mathrm{Re} \{ K \}$. Does maybe exist a more straightforward way in such a case?

${{}}$

Comment: You should rather write $K^2=\frac{c}{a+ib}$ express the right-hand side as a exponential and then take its square root.

Comment: Are you meaning

$$K^2 = \frac{ac}{a^2 + b^2} - i \frac{bc}{a^2 + b^2}$$ 

and so 

$$K^2 = \sqrt{\left( \frac{ac}{a^2 + b^2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{bc}{a^2 + b^2} \right)^2} e^{-i \arctan ((bc) / (ac))}$$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite solve it, but here are some thoughts to get you inspired:
$$x + iy = re^{i \theta} = K = \sqrt{ \frac{c}{a + bi}} = \sqrt{ \frac{c(a - bi)}{a^2 + b^2}} = \sqrt{ \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2} - i\frac{cb}{a^2 + b^2}}$$
We know that $tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{y}$ and $r = |z| = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}$.
Then$$ (x + iy)^2 = \bigg(\sqrt{ \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2} - i\frac{cb}{a^2 + b^2}}\bigg)^2$$
or
$$ x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy = \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2} - i\frac{cb}{a^2 + b^2}$$
and last you need to solve for x and y given
$$x^2 - y^2 = \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2}$$
and
$$2yx = - \frac{cb}{a^2 + b^2}$$
which I have to admit must be quite cumbersome. However, once you compute x and y, just plug them in $tan(\theta) = \frac{x}{y}$ and $r = |z| = \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}$ to find $\theta$ and $r$, and you are done.

Alternatively, you can start by squaring both sides:
$$ r^2e^{i 2\theta} = \bigg(\sqrt{ \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2} - i\frac{cb}{a^2 + b^2}}\bigg)^2$$
or 
$$ r^2e^{i 2\theta}  = \frac{ca}{a^2 + b^2} - i\frac{cb}{a^2 + b^2} $$
with $ r^2 = u^2 + v^2$, where u,v are the real and imaginary parts respectively in the above expression, and play around with the argument geometrically until find $\theta$, but I think that will be harder.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Let $K=\sqrt \frac{c}{a+ib}=x+iy$

On squaring both the sides -

$\frac{c}{a+ib}=(x+iy)^2$

$\frac{c}{a+ib}=x^2-y^2+2ixy$

Now multiply and divide LHS by $(a-ib)$

$\frac{c(a-ib)}{a^2-b^2}=x^2-y^2+2ixy$

On comparing real and imaginary coefficients, you can get values of $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a,b$ and $c$.

Then let $\sqrt {x^2+y^2}=\alpha$  and $\cos\beta = \frac{x}{\alpha} $.

Now,

$K=x+iy=\alpha(\frac{x}{\alpha}+i\frac{y}{\alpha})$

$K=\alpha e^{i\beta}$

$\alpha = \sqrt {x^2+y^2}$

$\beta = \arccos \frac {x}{\sqrt {x^2+y^2}}$